# CakePHP - How to access an Auth protected controller action with Node.js

Tags: node.js, cakephp-3.0

We have two environments (seperate servers):

- Webserver environment which is publicly available and running CakePHP 3.
- Worker environment which is not publicly available and running node.js for doing async stuff like message processing and query excecution.

So in theory the worker env queries our database looking for new entries, executing them and finally updating the database when done.

We want to use the existing controller actions provided by CakePHP (webserver env) for updating the database. The problem is that the add action of the controller is protected using the Auth component.

So our question is: How can we access an Auth protected controller action with node.js - **the correct way**?

Sorry that we don't provide any code - there is none yet. This is more or less a theoretical question and we would like to understand it first.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before is create a php command that runs that code, I don't know how that works in Cake PHP, but for instance on Symfony you could do something like this:

```
php app/console myApi:doAction --env=prod --data='{"data":{"isJson":true}}'
```

Node can run this command asynchronously and wait for it to finish, more over, your command could throw exceptions in JSON as well which you could parse. You can check [this](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) on how to do it.